# Why Tailwind Height doesn't work (breakpoints)?

Tags: css, laravel, height, tailwind-css, breakpoints

I installed Tailwind CSS and Elements on my Laravel project.

I'm doing the responsive part, but the "height" is not working when I use breakpoints (i.e "md:xxx").

I tried with other things like background color, width or flex, it's working.

```
<div class="bg-pink-500 md:bg-black h-16 md:h-64"></div>
```

The only change I made on Tailwind is to set my application color palette.

I see someone having the same issue and talking about a file missing (postcss.config.js).
I have postcss installed (v8.4.6) in my package.
I tried to manually create the file and fill with this (doesn't work) :

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
plugins: [
  require('postcss-import'),
  require('tailwindcss'),
  require('autoprefixer'),
 ]
}
```

Here is my code :

**HTML CSS links**

```
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

    {{-- Tailwind Components --}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/css/index.min.css" />
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]);

mix.sass('resources/scss/style.scss', 'public/css');
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
purge: [
    './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*js'
],

theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: {
            'montserrat': ['Montserrat'],
            sans: ['Montserrat'],
            serif: ['Montserrat'],
            mono: ['Montserrat'],
            display: ['Montserrat'],
            body: ['Montserrat']
            // sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        },
        colors: {
            'black1': '#181818',
            'black2': '#323232',
            'white0': '#F9F9F9',
            'white1': '#F1F1F1',
            'white2': '#E4E4E4',
            'red1': '#8E0000',
            'red2': '#BA0000',
            'red3': '#D62323'
          },
    },
},

variants: {
    extend: {
        opacity: ['disabled']
    },
},

plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms')
]

};
```

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

The css keeps default settings instead of using my breakpoint settings.

[Screenshot of CSS in dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hckna.png)

Answer (score 0):

Has you can see on the post's screenshot, the CSS file (*index.min.css*) coming from Tailwind CDN overwritte *app.css*, just call Tailwind CDN first:

```
    {{-- Tailwind Components --}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/css/index.min.css" />

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).